# Codeigniter or PHP : select a part of image as profile picture

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-processing, crop

I wanted to create a functionality as of facebook profile picture using codeigniter

where user can select the part of the image to be displayed as profile pic can anyone guide me on that

Any efforts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeIgniter has support for image cropping:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html

CI supports GD/GD2, NetPBM, and ImageMagick:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php
http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/
http://www.imagemagick.org/

Here are some manual ImageMagick examples:
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/

In PHP, ImageMagick may be executed using the `exec` function:

```
exec("convert my_image.jpg -resize 50% -crop 80x80+0+0 my_thumb.jpg", $report);
print_r($report);
```

PS. The UI is a different story!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [jCrop](http://code.google.com/p/jcrop/) (an MIT licensed JavaScript cropper w/ PHP back) with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to achieve a cropper similar to Facebook. jCrop also includes a PHP example in the download folder to give you an example of how they work together.